# Automator: compress selected files/folders with administrator permissions/privileges

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automator

I have an Automator service that I've bound to a shortcut to zip selected files/folders. However, when those files/folders are in a path like the "~/Library/Application Support" folder, I get an error similar to:

> Can't archive (file/folder) because you do not have permission to read it.

However, when I use the "compress" option from Finder's file menu, it works fine.

My Automator service is set up as follows:

1. service receives selected: files or folders in Finder.app
2. Create archive: save as: archive
3. where: same folder as input

I'm guessing I will need to use either shell or bash script to make this work but haven't got a clue where to begin to do so. Hopefully theres a simple answer to this that will let me zip anything selected in finder with administrator priveleges.

Comment: Try adding it to zip in terminal: `zip -jr filename.zip folder` and see if there is any permission error. If not, you can create a shell script and run it in Automator service.